# Impresspages Blog Plugin don't work

Tags: impresspages

I try install Blog Plugin from github but after copying files to Plugin folder and click activate - Plugin don't work (have inactive status in plugin panel).
Or during installation should do something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you install from github, you have to create Plugin/Blog directory and then copy files there.

Why don't you install it from http://market.impresspages.org?

Or event from within ImpressPages admin?

Comment: Blog plugin is not available in IP market and plugins space on admin panel. I mean version 4 ImpressPages.
Is available only from github? Unless I'm wrong :)

Comment: Ok Plugin works. Enough to change the name of the folder to Blog... Simple :) At first sight not much difference to NewsList plugin. I would say that NewsList is better for me... he missing only pagination functions ;)